# How to get the co-ordinated of point which is in-view in AmCharts5

Tags: reactjs, amcharts, amcharts5

I want to get the points which are only visible when you zoom/pan through the map.

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aT1u5.png) For example when I zoom into the map, I want to get only the points which are in view. There seems to be no direct way of doing this in the documentation. So any suggestions would be helpful